# How to replay Kafka backup on S3

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Kafka backup on S3 which is per-hour data. I would like to replay some of them, how can I import them to a topic and play them again? Also in this case how can I control the consuming speed?

Comment: Is it just a straight file backup? You just copied to logs to S3? Or is there a Kafka broker running on S3? And you back data up by sending it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install pv, and run:

cat ${files} | pv -L 800000 | ~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ${brokers} --topic ${topics}